# jQuery data() get incorrect number data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I user jQuery 1.6.1 and browse is Chrome 11

I put some data in DIV, like this:

```
<div id="user" data-user-id="68029454802354176"></div>
```

and try to use .data() to fetch the userId

```
console.log($('#user').data('userId'));
```

I must get **68029454802354176**, but it just return **68029454802354180**

Why does it change my number?

Comment: do you have multiple elements with the id user?

Comment: **[Getting the same problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpdKW/)**

Comment: You've exceeded the max integer value do var a = 68029454802354176; in your browser

Comment: Same thing happened to me, when I had uniqid() uid there: data-uid="51e0888381259" - data() thought it is float and gave me Infinity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i dont think this has any thing to do with jquery more how javascript handels big numbers

its to bad data returns a number and not a string in this case

```
  $("#user").attr("data-user-id")
```

will get you a correct string at lest

if you put 68029454802354176
in the chrome console it gives you 68029454802354180 back

Comment: @Drew yes, I think the number is exceeded.
I find a link here:[link](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

Finally, I use .attr() to get the value, but sadly can't use data() to get all values. I don't know why can't data() get string value.

Thanks guys help.

Comment: I would think this is a bug in data().  It's good that you can use attr(), you can also go the non jQuery route and pull it via HTML5 dataset() or HTML4 getAttribute() (probably called internally in attr(), but that's a complicated beast when I was looking on github).  Here's a sample http://jsfiddle.net/8zcdu/1/